# What is an optimal strategy for an user of hungarian algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, linear-programming

I wonder what is the optimal strategy for a player to adopt when dealing with a distribution using a Hungarian algorithm.(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm)

The situation is that of a pairing between n persons and m objects, where the persons make some ordered vows concerning their favorite object.

In the total absence of information on wishes of n-1 other people, I guess the optimal strategy to maximize one’s contentment is to actually order the vows according to one’s real preferences.

However, if you know the wishes of others, or if you have an estimate of the number of times each item is asked for, I think there may be an optimal “barrage” strategy to maximize your chance of getting the first wish by placing items in high demand afterwards.

However, since weights are linear in a Hungarian algorithm, I think this dam strategy is ineffective (compared to square weights in the wish index) and potentially risky.

After a little research, I could not find any documentation on the subject. Do you have good sources describing optimal strategies to deal with this kind of algorithm?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: As you've described the problem, there's no optimal strategy because it depends on the strategies of the other n-1 people. Knowing their preferences (ie: weights) is not enough.

Comment: (This isn't a programming problem, it's a game-theory question, so probably belongs on another site, once it's specified enough to be answerable).